# List not allowing .splitlines() - Python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

What do I need to do to prevent the error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split lines'` from occurring here?  How to I convert the list that I have into a form that can have `splitlines` attributed to?

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#Read csv
with open ("gyms4.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    csvfilelist = [row[0] for row in reader]

print csvfilelist

#Get data from each url
def get_page_data():
    for page_data in csvfilelist.splitlines():
        r = requests.get(page_data.strip())
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        yield soup
```

Comment: You already have a list. Why do you think you need to split it?

Comment: `list` doesn't have `splitlines`, `str` has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`str.splitlines()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) only works on a string object. You don't have a string object, you have a list of strings:

```
csvfilelist = [row[0] for row in reader]
```

There is no need to split this, you already have the first column of each line in the file. Just remove the `.splitlines()` call:

```
for page_data in csvfilelist:
```

Comment: Thanks Matijn, I originally began with using `csvfile = open("gyms4.csv")
urls = csvfile.read()`, which I why still had splitlines in there

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: are you saying that people trying to be helpful with an answer with documentation, to a question with full code and error message, is somehow not going to help others in the future with similar problems?

Comment: Exactly. Failing to see that the `list` type doesn't have the `.splitlines()` member is a simple oversight and thus this particular combination isn't likely to be a recurring problem.

Comment: For what it's worth I appreciated the time taken to fully explain what I was doing wrong, even though it is a relatively simple mistake.  I'm still learning, and have received less help than this for other questions, which has only compounded my confusion previously.